# What happens if AMD fTPM is enabled and a hardware TPM module is added later?

Tags: uefi, tpm, ftpm

I have a Asus hardware TPM module on order for my Asus Prime X470-Pro motherboard (using a AMD Ryzen 2600 CPU).
fTPM is currently enabled, but, to the best of my knowledge not used by any process. (No BitLocker. Nothing else that would be able to store/use a TPM key.)
(CSM is disabled, SecureBoot is enabled.)

Just because I'm cautious I will disable the fTPM before installing the hardware module, but I can't help wondering what would happen if I don't disable the fTPM first.
The logical thing would be for the motherboard to detect the hardware TPM and disable it, leaving it to the user to enable it and disable the fTPM in the UEFI settings. But, these things are not always logical...
Is it even technically possible to have BOTH active simultaneously? Would they conflict?

I'm asking this "in general", not just for my specific motherboard.

Does anybody know how the TPM and fTPM would interact?
Manuals don't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one TPM module can be active at one time. So one of the two will be deactivated. Usually if you have fTPM enabled, the other will automatically be disabled, so its very logical to assume that if you add another TPM module it will be disabled until disable the fTPM module.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this out and this is exactly what happened (at least on my Asus motherboard). fTPM remained active. After I set it OFF in bios it went to hardware TPM when switching TPM back on (and fTPM was no longer an option).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. :)